# How to trace "Parse error: syntax error" in a PHP program?

Tags: php

I've tried repl, linter and can't find what's missing. I am new to PHP.

> Error:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end on line 62

'Line 62' is the last line of code and it's for an email form for my site

Code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {


   $email_to = "(my email is in here)";
   $email_subject = "Enquiry";



   // validation expected data exists
   if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
       !isset($_POST['email']) ||
       !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
       died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
   }

   $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

   $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
   $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

   $error_message = "";
   $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
 if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
   $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
 }
   $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z\s.'-]+$/";
 if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
   $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
 }

 if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
   $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
 }
 if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
   died($error_message);
 }
   $email_message = "Details below.\n\n";

   function clean_string($string) {
     $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
     return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
   }

   $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

   $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
   $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_to."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
sleep(1);
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=\"0; url=http://kahlilashanti.com">";
?>

<?php
}
?>-->
```

Comment: You've posted code without a variable `$end` even mentioned, nothing anyone can do to help at this point.

Comment: Besides syntax errors which we can't help you with, your script has serious security issues.  No doubt it will be hijacked for spam purposes.  Anyone can send pretty much whatever they want through your script.  Also, your e-mail regex isn't good enough... you can't assume that the TLD is going to be 2-4 characters... and that's assume it isn't a TLD like `realtor`.

Comment: FYI - based on the answer below, it appears you've modified the error message from something like "Unexpected end of file" to "Unexpected $end"...

Comment: @Enstage the variable end - my point exactly.  Also error message began with the route to the actual file.

Comment: thx @Brad will def get on that. much appreciated

Comment: @KahlilAshanti, no. The end of the file is not a variable. `$end` does not mean the end of the file, `$end` is a variable name, it has NO relevance to the end of the file. You changed the error message to mean something entirely different.

Answer (score 2):

you have no escape on the double quote at the end of the content at the end of the line:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=\"0; url=http://kahlilashanti.com">";
```

should be

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=\"0; url=http://kahlilashanti.com\">";
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed '}' in the end of script. You started condition `if(isset($_POST['email'])) {` but didn't close it.